# Bash script number generator

Tags: bash, shell

I need to generate random numbers in an specific format as test data. For example, given a number "n" I need to produce "n" random numbers and write them in a file. The file must contain at most 3 numbers per line. Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

m=$1
output=$2

for ((i=1; i<= m; i++)) do
    echo $((RANDOM % 29+2)) >> $output
done
```

This outputs the numbers as:

```
1
2
24
21
10
14
```

and what I want is:

```
1 2 24
21 10 14
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure bash (written as a function rather than a script file)

```
randx3() {
  local d=$'  \n'
  local i
  for ((i=0;i<$(($1 - 1));++i)); do
    printf "%d%c" $((RANDOM%29 + 2)) "${d:$((i%3)):1}"
  done
  printf "%d\n" $((RANDOM%29 + 2))
}
```

Note that it doesn't take a file argument; rather it outputs to stdout, so you would use it like this:

```
randx3 11 > /path/to/output
```

That style is often more flexible.

Here's a less hacky one which allows you to select how often you want a newline:

```
randx() {
  local i
  local m=$1
  local c=${2:-3}
  for ((i=1;i<=m;++i)); do
    if ((i%c && i<m)); then
      printf "%d " $((RANDOM%29 + 2))
    else
      printf "%d\n" $((RANDOM%29 + 2))
    fi
  done
}
```

Call that one as `randx 11` or `randx 11 7` (second argument defaults to 3).

Comment: This worked fine :). Would you mind explain me this part? `${d:$((i%3)):1}`. What should I do if I want to group lines not by 3 numbers but by 7?

Comment: It's bash substring syntax; that's the one-character substring starting at $i%3, using 0-based indexing. Since d contains space, space, newline, that selects a newline every third time. If you wanted to change it to 7, you'd need to fix $d as well; I'd do that differently.

Comment: In second sample, you could re-use `"${d:$((i%c)):1}"` by setting: `printf -v d "%$((c-1))s\n"` to avoid `if ... then ... else`

Comment: @F.Hauri: I honestly don't remember, but I'm certainly aware of the issue. By the way, in English, the usual term is "non-uniform", since an unbiased random sample is "uniform". All the same, for producing random test cases, a 0.1% deviation from uniformity might be tolerable :-).

Answer (score 3):

Pipe the output to a command that will read 3 lines at a time:

```
for ((i=1; i<= m; i++)) do
    echo $((RANDOM % 29+2))
done | sed -e '$!N;$!N;s/\n/ /g' >> $output
```

Comment: That works fine for every m multiple of 3. However, if the value of m, for instance, is 5, the result I expect to have is: in the first line 3 numbers (i.e. 29 6 27) and in the second the two remaining numbers (12 9). How can I get that?
`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I need. Just a final question (for future use), if I need to read not 3 but 10 lines, is the best way to add "$!N" as I need (say 10, so the code is `sed -e '$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;s/\n/ /g' >> $output`? or is there a more "elegant" form.

Comment: @Chech No clever way comes to mind, but your command is correct for 10 lines

Answer (score 1):

This is what `paste` was designed for:

```
$ for i in {0..10}; do echo $RANDOM; done | paste -d' ' - - -
14567 3240 16354
17457 25616 12772
3912 7490 12206
7342 10554
```

Another approach would be to build up the values in an array, then use printf.

```
m=$1
output=$2
vals=()
while (( m-- )); do
  vals+=( $((RANDOM % 29+2)) )
done
printf '%d %d %d\n' "${vals[@]}" > "$output"
```

Comment: This works fine for m multiple of 3. But if I choose for example 5, I want the output to be the first line composed by 3 numbers and the second one with the remaining 2. How can I do that with this approach?

Comment: @Chech I'm not clear on how you derived those numbers. Why not 4 and 1 or 2 and 3?

Comment: your usage of `paste` worked for me like a charm thanks!. Now, the reason is because I need to receive 2 parameters (n & k) where n is the amount of random numbers generated and k is the maximum numbers per line. If n=5 and k=3 then the output should be as I mentioned above. However, as I told you, the paste command worked fine, I'll read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Shortest!!!

> I need to produce "n" random numbers and write them in a file. The file must contain at most 3 numbers per line.

```
pr -t -3 -s\  <(for ((n=6;n--;)){ echo $((RANDOM % 29+2));}) >file
```

Then

```
cat file
11 29 27
14 21 22
```

#### *YAS*: Yet another [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution

As a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$1
file=$2
out=()
>$file
for ((i=1;i<=n;i++));do
    out+=($((RANDOM%29+2)))
    [ $((i%3)) -eq 0 ] && echo ${out[*]} >>$file && out=()
  done
[ "$out" ] && echo ${out[*]} >>$file
```

Usage:

```
script <quantity of random> <filename>
```

#### Important remark about `RANDOM%29`

This way of rendering random between 2 to 30 **is not equitable!**

As `$RANDOM` give a number between `0` and `32767`, there is:

```
for ((i=0;i<32768;i++)) ;do
    ((RL[$((i%29+2))]++))
  done
for ((i=0;i<32;i++));do
    printf "%3d %5d\n" $i ${RL[i]}
  done | column 

  0     0     7  1130        14  1130        21  1130        28  1130
  1     0     8  1130        15  1130        22  1130        29  1129
  2  1130     9  1130        16  1130        23  1130        30  1129
  3  1130    10  1130        17  1130        24  1130        31     0
  4  1130    11  1130        18  1130        25  1130
  5  1130    12  1130        19  1130        26  1130
  6  1130    13  1130        20  1130        27  1130
```

... there is 1130 chances to obtain a number between 2 to 28, but *only* 1129 chances to obtain a 29 or a 30.

To prevent this, you have to **drop** unwanted results:

```
random2to30() {
    local _random=32769
    while (( $_random>=32741 )) ;do
        _random=$RANDOM;
    done;
    printf -v $1 "%d" $((2+_random%29))
}
```

The proof:

```
tstr2to30() {
    unset $1
    local _random=32769
    while (( $_random>=32741 )); do
        read _random || break
    done
    [ "$_random" ] && printf -v $1 "%d" $((2 +_random % 29 ))
}
unset RL
while tstr2to30 MyRandom && [ "$MyRandom" ] ;do
    ((RL[MyRandom]++))
  done < <(seq 0 32767)
for ((i=0;i<32;i++));do
    printf "%3d %5d\n" $i ${RL[i]}
  done | column
```

Give:

```
  0     0     7  1129        14  1129        21  1129        28  1129
  1     0     8  1129        15  1129        22  1129        29  1129
  2  1129     9  1129        16  1129        23  1129        30  1129
  3  1129    10  1129        17  1129        24  1129        31     0
  4  1129    11  1129        18  1129        25  1129
  5  1129    12  1129        19  1129        26  1129
  6  1129    13  1129        20  1129        27  1129
```

Where all value do obtain exactly same (1129) chances!

#### Final useable script

So the script could become (Don't forget bash's shebang!):

```
#!/bin/bash

n=${1:-11}                  # default to 11 values
c=${2:-3}                   # default to 3  values by lines
minval=${3:-2}              # default to 2  random min
maxval=${4:-30}             # defailt to 30 random max
file=${5:-/dev/stdout}      # default to STDOUT

rnum=$(( maxval - minval + 1 ))
rmax=$(( ( 32768 / rnum ) * rnum ))
randomGen() {
    local _random=33000
    while [ $_random -ge $rmax ] ;do
        _random=$RANDOM
      done
    printf -v $1 "%d" $(( minval +_random % rnum ))
}

out=()
for ((i=1;i<=n;i++));do
    randomGen MyRandom
    out+=($MyRandom)
    [ $((i%c)) -eq 0 ] && echo ${out[*]} >>"$file" && out=()
  done
[ "$out" ] && echo ${out[*]} >>"$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk will insert a newline after every 3rd line or a space:

```
for ((i=1; i<= m; i++)); do
    echo $((RANDOM % 29+2))
done | awk '{printf "%s%c", $1, (NR % 3) ? " " : "\n"}' >> $output
```

Comment: I can't figure out where to put this line in my code in order to get the expected output file. Besides, what is the meaning of NR?

Comment: `NR` is the number of records (records usually == lines) in the file.

Comment: I've added some context to my answer. And `NR` is the number of the line currently being processed. E.g. `echo -e "a\nb\nc" | awk '{print NR}'` will print 1 2 3.

Answer (score 0):

yet another way of doing it :

```
eval echo {1..$m} | xargs -n3 echo $((RANDOM % 29+2)) > $output
```